# Can't fetch userCKRecordID with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, cloudkit

I am getting the error: "Value of type 'CKDatabase' has no member 'fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler'." Was it taken out of the newest version of Xcode or swift 3?

```
func fetchUserRecords()
    {
        let publicDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        publicDB.fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler { (userID, error) -> Void in
            if let userID = userID {
                let reference = CKReference(recordID: userID, action: .None)
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "creatorUserRecordID == %@", reference)
                let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Location", predicate: predicate)
                CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil){
                    (records, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error fetching user records: \(error)")
                        completion(error as NSError?, nil)
                    } else {
                        print("found user records")
                        completion(nil, records)
                        guard let records = records else {
                            return
                        }
                        for record in records
                        {
                            //delete records
                        }
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at the docs for `CKContainer`, not `CKDatabase`.

Comment: I looked at the document and changed it to "CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID" @rmaddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 3 changes the names of lots of function calls. The new function signature is

`func fetchUserRecordID(completionHandler: @escaping (CKRecordID?, Error?) -> Void)`

### EDIT:

rmaddy reports that the function is a function of `CKContainer`, not `CKDatabase`.

Comment: You left out the really important part. This is a method of `CKContainer`, not `CKDatabase`.

Comment: I also changed "publicDB.fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler..."" to "CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID..." @Duncan C

Comment: @rmaddy, I've never used CloudKit, so I did not realize that. I saw your comment though...